# Проблема с REST 1C

Tags: rest, 1с

Стал разбираться с получением данных из 1С через REST сервис и возникла такая проблема. При запросе к одинаковым базам(одна является копией другой) приходят разные значения metadata. Может кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным ?

Comment: что значит "приходят разные значения metadata"? Приведите пример хотя бы.

Comment: Для примера, выполняю запрос  
protocol://server/ref_test/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_ШтатноеРасписание?$format=json  
protocol://server/ref_work/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_ШтатноеРасписание?$format=json  

В результате первого приходят данные, а в результате второго нет. 
Стал смотреть запрос   
protocol://server/ref/odata/standard.odata/$metadata для обеих баз.  
В результате как раз отсутствует данный каталог.

Answer (score 0):

Есть большая вероятность, что в базе ref_work не опубликован стандартный интерфейс OData - просто не стоит галка в публикации базы. Так же может быть, что вообще вторая база не опубликована для доступа извне, либо фаерволом закрыты порты для доступа к базе (80 или 443 в зависимости от протокола).